# How do I install a particular version of ros-melodic-franka-ros

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 for implementing robot(franka emika panda) with custom controller.
I was away for a week, but the controller I used was not running well, so I checked the problem.

Compared to other working computers, it seems that there was a problem with the update of "franka-ros" to the latest version.
So, I tried to install the previous version(0.7.1-1bionic.20210304.174422) of franka-ros with following command

- sudo apt install ros-melodic-franka-ros=0.7.1-1bionic.20210304.174422

Then, the results is as follows.

- E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-frank-ros-0.7.1-1bionic.20210304.174422

I already added 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main' in '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'.
by following commands

- sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
- sudo apt-key adv --keyserver 'hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80' --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654
- sudo apt update

I was wondering if there was a way to install an older version of "ros-melodic-franka-ros"

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/398008/how-do-i-install-a-particular-version-of-ros-melodic-franka-ros/) by [injeyi](https://answers.ros.org/users/100392/injeyi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2022-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'd have to build it from source, in your workspace. The ROS package repositories do not retain older versions of released packages. That's a limitation of the `apt` repository backend.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [injeyi](https://answers.ros.org/users/100392/injeyi/) on 2022-03-27**:
Thank you for help, I solved it through "https://frankaemika.github.io/docs/installation_linux" as you said
Actually, I did it before, but I missed to change command 'kinetic' to 'melodic'